# Does URL.getText() always close the connection?

Tags: url, groovy

In the Groovy JDK URL enhancement is a series of functions called `getText()`; a plain one without parameters, and variants that have `String charset` and/or `Map parameters` as arguments.

The versions that take `String charset` as parameters state in the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html#getText()) "*The connection stream is closed before this method returns.*" However, those versions that do *not* have the `charset` parameter do not mention it.

Is this an oversight in the documentation? Are the functions behaving differently in that respect? Or am I reading too much into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the connection stream will always be closed, yes.  From the source: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ResourceGroovyMethods.java#L614 it looks like all of these `getText(...)` methods just call one of two endpoints, both of which do close the stream.